# Hiding NSTableView header?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

How do I hide an NSTableView header completely, so that it does not take any space up?

Comment: +1 for asking a good question.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

In Interface Builder, select the table view, open the attributes inspector (alt-command-4), and uncheck the "Headers" checkbox in the "Columns" section.

Comment: This was not easy to find! Thank you!

Comment: Works also for `NSOutlineView`, obviously (Table View section of the attributes inspector).

Answer (score 42):

You can also set the headerView programmatically without subclassing

```
[tableView setHeaderView:nil];
```

Answer (score 8):

To do this programmatically, you can subclass NSTableView (or any NSTableView child class) and return nil for the headerView variable:

```
@interface AppTableView : NSTableView {

}

@end

@implementation AppTableView

- (NSTableHeaderView *)headerView{
    return nil;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5

```
tableView.headerView = nil
```