# Set custom HeaderView for each Column in NSTableView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, nstableheaderview

Is it possible to set a custom header view for each Column in NSTable ? When I drag drop a table to a view, I can see that there is only 1 header view for both the columns. I referred [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4037116/366346) and implemented same in my table class.

```
- (NSTableHeaderView *)headerView{
    CustomHeaderView *customHeader = [[CustomHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame: ...];
    return customHeader;
}
```

But this will add one view for all the table columns.
If my understanding is correct, TableHeaderView is only one view, and default header view looks like it contains 2 cells for both columns but its actually one view. ? If so how do I go about having separate views or mimic the same behaviour for custom header view ?