# NSTableView column header don't show

Tags: macos, interface-builder, tableview

With Xcode 9.2, I'm working on a macOS project with two different windows.

In one of the windows, I have a view-based tableView with one column, the header of the column is regularly shown. In another window, there is a similar tableView, but the header (which is visible in IB), at runtime is not shown.

I compare the properties of the two tableViews in IB but they are the same. Also, the **Header** checkbox in the **Table View** section (which has a role in this UI element, as described in a reply to this question [Hiding NSTableView header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514210/hiding-nstableview-header)) is checked.

What could the problem depend on?

TableView Properties pane:

[image: TableView Properties pane]

Interface Builder:

[image: Interface Builder]

Runtime:

[image: Runtime]

Edited:

```
class EditTasksController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     self.actionsListTableView.dataSource = self
     self.actionsListTableView.delegate = self

     actionsListTableView.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
     actionsListTableView.headerView = nil

     func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {

     ...
```

Comment: What does the code look like? Are you modifying / messing with the header in e.g. `viewForTableColumn:`?

Comment: @TheNextman, thank you for the comment, I edited the question including the code

Comment: Use Xcode's view debugger to inspect the view hierarchy at run time.  It will show you locations, sizes, and z-order of views.

Comment: `actionsListTableView.headerView = nil`. Remove this line.

Comment: Thank you for your comment about Xcode's view debugger Phillip Mills, I will definitely use this technique. @TheNextman it worked, please answer the question so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
actionsListTableView.headerView = nil
```

Removes the header from the table. Remove that line of code, and the header will be visible.